# Matlab custom class browser or class representation

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I am writing the documentation of some custom classes I implemented in Matlab, and I would like to include a diagram to show the classes’ members and relationships. Is there an object browser implemented in Matlab? Or more in general, is there an efficient way to represent class structure?

The best I came up with is along these lines, but it can get very messy:

```
Object:
    Methods:
        Method1
        Method2
    Properties
        Property1
        PropertyObject
            Methods:
                Method1
                Method2
            Properties
                Property1
```

Comment: `doc classname` shows all methods and properties (maybe only public ones?). That gets you 99% there. Properties that are a class could be linked to, it's easy to add a `see also classname` in the help line for a property. I think writing `CLASSNAME` also adds a link.

Comment: Thats's a very good starting point. It is unfortunate that it does not show private methods and properties...